# Synonyms for practice

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I was writing an essay about fairness or appropriateness of taking older family members to retirement homes. Throughout the essay I had to refer to **"taking family member to retirement homes"** as **"this practice"** several times. For example I would say:

- Many people find **this practice** cruel and unfair.
- There are many merits to **this practice**.
- **This practice** can make things easier for both the families and the elderly.
- A closer look reveals many advantages for **this practice**.

I have already looked up synonyms for practice in a few dictionaries. Words like habit, tradition, method, ... do not really fit. Are there any other words that I can use in these sentences to avoid the repetition of the word "**practice**"?

Comment: If the context makes it clear what you're talking about, you can just say ***this*** or even ***it***.

Comment: These sentences do not immediately come after each other. There are multiple sentences between these references. So "this" or "it" won't work.

Answer (score 5):

This *course of action,* works. You could also say "convention" when referring to the societal trend of depositing the elderly in institutions.

Comment: Good one.  "action" is the closest to "a drop-in replacement for 'practice'".  "Procedure" can work sometimes.

Comment: I'd add _standard_ to that as well.  A lot of people synonymize _convention_, _best practice_, and _standard_ which, in my world, is a mistake, as each are subtly different, but in the OP's world, the essay about the elderly, they could probably get away with using them as such.

Answer (score 2):

These are the words I could think of to 'avoid the repetition of the word "practice"':

option

choice

alternative

preference

action

recourse

Answer (score 2):

Based on the excerpts you chose to include in the OP, I would surmise that you intend to convey a positive, rather than a negative, view of retirement homes. If so, you may want to minimize use of the term “*practice*,” which carries connotations of habitual and repetitive, or automatic and unthinking action. Rather, whenever appropriate, you may want to emphasize that the placement of an elder loved-one in a retirement home (never, *facility*) is a positive “**choice**” resulting from a thoughtful consideration of all “**options**” available.

My suggestion then is, accentuate the usage of terms such as “**choice**”, “**alternative**”, “**selection**”, and “**options**”, when possible.

Answer (score 1):

As Janus says, if the context makes clear what you are talking about, you could just say this. However, if you want to use synonyms, maybe you could use ***tendency***, ***trend***, ***behaviour*** or ***demeanour***

Answer (score 1):

You could vary things a bit by talking about "retirement homes" instead of "taking family member to retirement homes". e.g.

There are many merits to retirement homes.
Retirement homes can make things easier for both the families and the elderly.
A closer look reveals many advantages for retirement homes.

Answer (score 1):

*[Convention](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=convention%20meaning)* is another choice:

> a way in which something is usually done, especially within a
>   particular area or activity.

It's slightly more used as a particular practice within a field (so possibly how the retirement home operates, not just the thing in general) but it could still substitute for some of your "practices"

*There are many merits to this convention.*